# Криптование Android-Php

Tags: php, android, mcrypt

Проблема вот в чём, криптуем в php файл разбивая его на 4096 байт с помощью библиотеке [MCrypt](https://github.com/serpro/Android-PHP-Encrypt-Decrypt)

```
            while (!feof($fd)) {
                print $mcrypt->encrypt(fread($fd, 4096),true,$key);
            }
            fclose($fd);
```

и скачиваем его с помощью DownloadManager.Request в Android устройство, дальше не пойму как открыть файл чтобы прочитать его правильно и расшифровать? делаю как то так, ну думаю не правильно

```
byte[] read = null;
//                int size = file.read(read);
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int size = 0;
                int chars = file.read();
                while (size < 4096 && chars != -1) {
                    buffer.append((char) chars);
                    chars = file.read();
                    size++;
                }
//                String decrypted = new String(read, "UTF-8");
                String decrypted = new String(buffer.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                read = mCrypt.decrypt(decrypted);
```

Comment: а цель какая в этом?

Comment: есть pdf файл его надо зашифровать и зашифрованным скачать, и потом открыть с помощью библиотеки radaeepdf
может у кого то есть решение для криптования файла чтобы эта либа открыла то есть там есть PDFAESStream и вот с помощью этого класса открыть?